apache beam| unable to install apache beam and showing subprocess error
I have installed latest pip, python 3.12, and what not.. still this error is showing:
" Building wheels for collected packages: grpcio-tools
Building wheel for grpcio-tools (setup.py): started
Building wheel for grpcio-tools (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
    python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
    exit code: 1

    [101 lines of output]
    C:\Users\nilab\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i0cdhjus\grpcio-tools_b92530db0944414b912a68ceee125f69\setup.py:30: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
      import pkg_resources
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc_tools
    copying grpc_tools\command.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc_tools
    copying grpc_tools\protoc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc_tools
    copying grpc_tools\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc_tools
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc_tools\_proto
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc_tools\_proto\google
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
    copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\any.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
    copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\api.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
    copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\duration.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
    copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\empty.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
    copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\field_mask.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
    copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\source_context.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
    copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\struct.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
    copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\timestamp.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
    copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\type.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
    copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\wrappers.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\compiler
    copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\compiler\plugin.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\compiler
    copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\descriptor.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
    running build_ext
    building 'grpc_tools._protoc_compiler' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\grpc_root
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\grpc_root\src
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\grpc_root\src\compiler
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\grpc_tools
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\third_party
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\third_party\protobuf
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\third_party\protobuf\src
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf    
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\cpp
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\csharp
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\java
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\objectivec
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\php
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\python
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\ruby
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\io 
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\stubs
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\util
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\util\internal
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN=1 -DMS_WIN64=1 -I. -Igrpc_root -Igrpc_root\include -Ithird_party\protobuf\src -IE:\Switch_Plan\Python\myenv\include -IC:\Users\nilab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include -IC:\Users\nilab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /EHsc /Tpgrpc_root\src\compiler\proto_parser_helper.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\grpc_root\src\compiler\proto_parser_helper.obj -std=c++14 /MT
    cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/MD' with '/MT'
    cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c++14'
    proto_parser_helper.cc
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN=1 -DMS_WIN64=1 -I. -Igrpc_root -Igrpc_root\include -Ithird_party\protobuf\src -IE:\Switch_Plan\Python\myenv\include -IC:\Users\nilab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include -IC:\Users\nilab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /EHsc /Tpgrpc_root\src\compiler\python_generator.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\grpc_root\src\compiler\python_generator.obj -std=c++14 /MT
    cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/MD' with '/MT'
    cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c++14'
    python_generator.cc
    grpc_root\src/compiler/python_generator_helpers.h(104): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    grpc_root\src/compiler/python_generator_helpers.h(104): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'const int', possible loss of data
    grpc_root\src\compiler\python_generator.cc(852): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    grpc_root\src\compiler\python_generator.cc(893): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    grpc_root\src\compiler\python_generator.cc(893): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'const int', possible loss of data
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN=1 -DMS_WIN64=1 -I. -Igrpc_root -Igrpc_root\include -Ithird_party\protobuf\src -IE:\Switch_Plan\Python\myenv\include -IC:\Users\nilab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include -IC:\Users\nilab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /EHsc /Tpgrpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.obj -std=c++14 /MT
    cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/MD' with '/MT'
    cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c++14'
    _protoc_compiler.cpp
    C:\Users\nilab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\pyconfig.h(130): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
    C:\Users\nilab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\pyconfig.h(130): note: 'MS_WIN64' previously declared on the command line
    grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(2181): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(3749): warning C4996: 'PyDictObject::ma_version_tag': deprecated in 3.12
    grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(3889): warning C4996: 'PyDictObject::ma_version_tag': deprecated in 3.12
    grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(4048): warning C4996: 'PyDictObject::ma_version_tag': deprecated in 3.12
    grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(4157): warning C4996: 'PyDictObject::ma_version_tag': deprecated in 3.12
    grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(6363): warning C4996: 'PyDictObject::ma_version_tag': deprecated in 3.12
    grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(7110): warning C4996: 'PyDictObject::ma_version_tag': deprecated in 3.12
    grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(7122): warning C4996: 'PyDictObject::ma_version_tag': deprecated in 3.12
    grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(7126): warning C4996: 'PyDictObject::ma_version_tag': deprecated in 3.12
    grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(7143): warning C4996: 'PyDictObject::ma_version_tag': deprecated in 3.12
    grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(7336): error C2039: 'curexc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
    C:\Users\nilab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/pystate.h(115): note: see declaration of '_ts'
    grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(7339): error C2039: 'curexc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
    C:\Users\nilab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/pystate.h(115): note: see declaration of '_ts'
    grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(8239): warning C4996: 'PyDictObject::ma_version_tag': deprecated in 3.12
    grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(8540): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
    C:\Users\nilab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
    grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(8595): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
    C:\Users\nilab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
    grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(8774): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
    C:\Users\nilab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
    grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(8829): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
    C:\Users\nilab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
    grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(8970): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
    C:\Users\nilab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
    grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9025): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
    C:\Users\nilab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
    grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(10675): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
    C:\Users\nilab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.39.33519\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    [end of output]

    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for grpcio-tools
    Running setup.py clean for grpcio-tools
  Failed to build grpcio-tools
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for grpcio-tools, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
  [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip."
I AM STUCK WITH CREATING DATA PIPELINE FROM GCS TO BIGQUERY THROUGH LOCAL MACHINE. PLEASE HELP ME FIX THIS.
i have installed latest pip, tried reinstall latest python version and added path, installed microsoft c++ tools, but still it is not working.

As of today, the apache-beam 2.55.1 version supports python 3.8, 3.9, 3.10, 3.11 and not 3.12 version.
Source: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/support/beam-runtime-support#python

Check https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/29149 to track.
